# Connecting Multiple Panda Dataframes & Calling a Dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

How do we write a function `car_id_type(df1, df2, df3)` such that the function adds a column `car_id` to the dataframe `df1` with the dict value for `car_brand` from `Car_Dictionary`?

```
Car_Dictionary = {'Toyota': 4, 'Nissan': 11, 'Ford': 6, 'Honda': 2}

    df1
    house_id     plane_id
    1122         7771

    df2
    plane_id      bike_id
    7771          457

    df3
    bike_id       car_brand
    457           Nissan

    df4
    house_id      plane_id    car_id
    1122          7771        11
```

Comment: What have you tried? And why do df2 and df3 have anything to do with df1?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, here is a solution:

```
def car_id_type(df1, df2, df3):
    df4 = df1.merge(df2).merge(df3)
    df4['car_id'] = df4.car_brand.map(Car_Dictionary)
    return df4[list(df1.columns)+['car_id']]

>>> car_id_type(df1, df2, df3)
   house_id  plane_id  car_id
0      1122      7771      11
```

It first merges the 3 dataframes on their shared columns (line: `df1.merge(df2).merge(df3)`), resulting in the following dataframe (note that this only works properly if they all share 1 column name):

```
   house_id  plane_id  bike_id car_brand
0      1122      7771      457    Nissan
```

And then, you make a new column `car_id`, mapping the value of `car_brand` to your `Car_Dictionary` (line: `df4['car_id'] = df4.car_brand.map(Car_Dictionary)`), finally returning all the columns in `df1` + the new column `car_id`.